# Animate OnComplete firing too early

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm implementing a progress bar (for timing a background task, I already know the exact time it will take) - but I'm having trouble with the oncomplete event firing early.

```
$("#go").on("click", function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    $('#report-loader .bar').animate({ 
        width: 500 
    },
    {   
        easing: 'linear',
        duration: 500,
        complete: function() {
            alert('complete');        
        }          
    });
});
```

​
​

Here's a JSFiddle that shows an example of what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/ezE8b/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace  : 
`$('#report-loader .bar').animate({ 
        width: 500 
    },`
 

by
 
`$('#report-loader .bar').animate({ 
        width: "100%" 
    },`


Works fine for me.

Comment: Fantastic, that works - I don't know why it wouldn't work with a px value though? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know either. (Please accept the answer if it answers your question)

Comment: Maybe `width: "500px"` will also work there is chance that just a number without units cause some confusion behind the scenes.

Comment: Ha! Welcome to the HTML world :-) `width: 500` works fine in my browser, but it doesn't in yours. Typical.